# Desktop PC won't start but reseating the RAM fixes it?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I have an older Desktop PC which has started to fail.  It will appear to power on (power light, spinning fans, and lights and fans on GPU) but no video output (GPU or onboard video) and no beeps then after 5-6 seconds will reset (lights and fans go off, then it starts again).  It will continue running for 5-6 seconds and then restarting until turned off at the PSU.

I tried isolating the problem by removing components, but discovered the moving RAM sticks to different slots completely resolves the problem, and it will boot and run fine.  Once it has booted up, it works normally and you can leave it on for days and it works fine.  But then next time it is shut down, it goes back to failing to boot - until the RAM is moved again, back to the original slots.  It has gone into this state and been "fixed" by moving them back and forth at least 10 times now.

Removing other components, such as GPU, hard drives, network card, (EDIT: and CMOS battery) doesn't make any difference.  Swapping the RAM modules for new ones has the same effect as moving the old ones to different slots.

The PC has the following components:

- Gigabyte GA-Z97P-D3 ATX LGA1150 Motherboard
- Intel Core i5-4690 3.50Ghz
- 16GB RAM (2x DDR3 1600)
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 980

What could be going on here?  What steps can I take to diagnose the issue?

Comment: "What steps can I take to diagnose the issue?" - You would have to start to replace hardware, since you have done everything else you can, to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Replacing the RAM didn't help.  What should be next?  I was thinking either PSU or motherboard, but I can't think how failures in either would cause these symptoms, when the act of reseating the RAM temporarily resolves it.   I don't have any spare part to test with, so I'm trying to understand better before buying parts.

Comment: Cheapest first swap would be a new CMOS battery. I've had computers doing all kinds of random sh*t in the past… whilst never dropping settings/date etc; which were fixed with a $1 CR2032.

Comment: @ColinPickard - Trying to find a motherboard for EOS hardware will be difficult, at best, you would be paying a premium on that hardware without any guarantees the issue isn't something simpler like a CMOS battery needing to be replaced. At this point, you have tried the common things we would suggest, we would just be picking at random straws suggesting hardware repleacements.

Comment: Argh, I forgot to included I already tried a new CMOS battery, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps the PSU needs replacement. Note : A repair shop can try replacing components at no cost to you.

Comment: "no beeps" have you heard beeps before (i.e. are you sure there is a speaker attached in some way to the mainboard to emit beep codes)? It does seem like a double-POST where it is trying to store config prior to a soft restart..

Comment: When you power off the PC, remove the power cord and press the power button (to drain all residual power in the PSU - trust me, it doesn't hurt, but it can make a difference) - now reconnect the power and turn on - does it still require memory swap? Also, have you tried with a single memory stick?

Comment: @ColinPickard did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not yet.  I did buy a replacement PSU, but the problem still occurs